# unprovoced rotation in unity transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so i am trying to make it so that if i press or hold A or D it should rotate 80 degrees (not more) but it just keeps rotating after it hits 80 degrees and then if i press A first and then immediately D it will stop rotating mid-air half upside down, how do i fix this, have been pulling my hair out for this one.

part the code:

```
if (horizontal < 0)
    {
        if (model.transform.rotation.z < 80)
        {
            model.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 160 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (model.transform.rotation.z > 80)
        {
            model.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(model.transform.rotation.x, model.transform.rotation.y, 80, model.transform.rotation.w);
        }
        if (model.transform.rotation.z <= -1)
        {
            model.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -160 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
if (horizontal == 0)
    {
        if (model.transform.rotation.z > 0)
        {
            model.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -160 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (model.transform.rotation.z < 0)
        {
            model.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 160 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

there is also an identical but reversed code for the horizontal > 0, oh and model.transform is a variable leading to the child object i want to rotate (set as a public Transform, not GameObject), tell me if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so i solved it, instead of just `model.transform.rotation.z` i had to put in `model.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z`, if anybody else needed help :).